# DropDownListFor not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Getting some weird behavior on a dropdownlistfor() but it's using a list so perhaps i got something wrong

the code is simple enough

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Phones.Count; i++ )
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Phones[i].Num)</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Phones[i].Typ, list1 )</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

where list1 is defined in the .cshtml itself as

```
string[] types = new string[] { "Office", "Mobile", "Home" };
List<SelectListItem> list1 = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach(var t in types){
    list1.Add(new SelectListItem{Text = t, Value = t });
```

the problem is the correct values are not being selected in the dropdown

[image: pls see screenshot here]

whereas the dropdowns should be Mobile, Office, Home

The code is pretty vanilla, it's the standard html.DropdownListFor() helper so looks like it's not generating the correct selected attribute on the  tag !!

what gives ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that all your `DropDownListFor` end up using the same list of options.  And the list of options itself contains the selected option.  So when the list is updated with the selected option for one list, all the previous ones are updated too.

Use something like this instead:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Phones[i].Typ, 
    new SelectList(list1, "DataValueFieldName", "TextValueFieldName", 
    m => m.Phones[i].Typ)
```

This will generate a new unique list for each drop down list.  Replace "DataValueFieldName" and "TextValueFieldName" with the names of the properties of the objects in `list1` containing the value and text to display respectfully.  If `list1` is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, then you can use "Value" and "Text".